# The customization content in iframe for Dynamics Crm got messed up for one customer. CSS does not respond correctly

Tags: css, customization, dynamics-crm-2011, ie-plugins

I am working on Dynamics Crm plugin. We add some new customization in lead view page and some other new pages. All these customization happen in iframe. These UI customization works perfectly on our machines.

However, one of our customer is experiencing some ui issue. The weird thing is, when I opened their account from my computer, it looks alright. Somehow when they opened the same account in any computer in their company, it shows some messy stuff. Some Css are not respected.

The other fact is that when the customer opened their QA account using our plugin in their computer, nothing looks wrong.

We are using exactly the same version of IE (9.0.13). I am not sure if ie plugin could make a difference for ui customized within Iframe.

I am completely out of my mind. Does anyone ever experience similar thing or can someone provide any clue please? Many thanks.

Comment: Any chance there are multiple forms and they're looking at a different form based on their role?

Comment: Thanks Daryl. I shared screen with our customer and confirmed it's the same form.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't using the client for Outlook? If they do, it's likely due to the Trident version of IE that's used for rendering the contents.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. They are just using IE. Still got no clue. And just observed one from another customer.